# JDO unowned many to many relationship

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jdo

I am creating a Cloud Endpoint in Google App Engine with JDO. I have two entities. The User entity contains a list of groups. The group entity contains a list of members which are user entities.

**User Entity:**

```
@PersistenceCapable(identityType = IdentityType.APPLICATION) public class USER {
        @PrimaryKey
        @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
        Key userid;

        @Persistent
        String name; 

        @Persistent
        private Set<GROUP> groups; //getters setters
```

**Group Entity**

```
@PersistenceCapable(identityType = IdentityType.APPLICATION) public class GROUP {
        @PrimaryKey
        @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
        Key groupid;

        @Persistent
        String name;  

        @Persistent
        private Set<USER> members; //getters setters
```

**My API Method**

```
@ApiMethod(name = "INSERT_CIRCLE")
    public wmcircle insertcircle(CIRCLE circle) {
        PersistenceManager mgr = getPersistenceManager();
        try {
            if (contains(circle)) {
                throw new EntityExistsException("Object already exists");
            }

            mgr.makePersistent(circle);
        } finally {
            mgr.close();
        }
        return circle;
    }
```

When I create a group GAE creates the user entities which the circle owns and sets the relationship but thats not the behavior I want. I want that I can set the relationship to existing user entities.

Comment: any Google "unowned" relationship needs @Unowned on the respective fields, and "mappedBy"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to manage an unowned many-to-many relationship is to save a collection of Keys on both sides of the relationship (see the [GAE JDO Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jdo/relationships#Unowned_Relationships)). So in your case, the entities will look like this:

**User**

```
...
@Persistent
private Set<Key> groups; 

//getters setters

public void addGroup(Group group) {
    groups.add(group.getKey());
    group.getMembers().add(this.getKey());
}

public void removeGroup(Group group) {
    groups.remove(group.getKey());
    group.getMembers().remove(this.getKey());
}
```

**Group**

```
...
@Persistent
private Set<Key> members; 

//getters setters

public void addMember(User member) {
    members.add(member.getKey());
    member.getGroups().add(this.getKey());
}

public void removeMember(User member) {
    members.remove(member.getKey());
    member.getGroups().remove(this.getKey());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is this all I have to change or do I have to change something in my API Method as well?

My API Method looks like this:

`@ApiMethod(name = "insertuser")
 public user insertuser(user user) {
  PersistenceManager mgr = getPersistenceManager();
  try {
   if(user.getKey() != null) {
    if (containsuser(user)) {
     throw new EntityExistsException("Object already exists");
    }
   }
   
   mgr.makePersistent(user);
  } finally {
   mgr.close();
  }
  return user;
 }`

Comment: OK a few things for you to consider: make sure you deleted "private Set<GROUP> groups; " and "private Set<USER> members;" when you added the Key sets instead. Also make sure you add getters/setters for the key sets so JDO picks it up (or make them public). Before you call insertuser() on the client side, add any group keys to the user. Finally within insertuser(), iterate through any group keys and update those entities with this new user who is part of those groups. Just remember: update the other side of the relationship whenever you update one side. Hope this helps!